# Can I use gsub and Hashes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, gsub

I want to go through my input and replace the words with 300 pairs of antonyms in Ruby.

In Python, creating a dictionary is an efficient way to do that, comparing using `replace`.

In Ruby, if I use `gsub!` line by line, is it much less efficient than using a Hash? Does it make a difference if I have only 300 pairs?

```
body=ARGV.dup

body.gsub!("you ","he ")
body.gsub!("up","down ")
body.gsub!("in ","out ")
body.gsub!("like ","hate ")
body.gsub!("many ","few ")
body.gsub!("good ","awesome ")
body.gsub!("all ","none ")
```

Comment: How your body looks like ? Give sample inputs..and expected outputs too

Comment: The inputs is sentences being translated using voice recognition,and system is checking the voice every 5 seconds.For example, in one 5 seconds if  the sentence is " 100 reasons I love you", and it will become " 100 reasons I hate you". etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a hash:

```
subs = {
  "you" => "he",
  etc.
}
subs.default_proc = proc {|k| k}
body.gsub(/(?=\b).+(?=\b)/, subs)
```

If, for efficiency, you need `gsub!`, use this:

```
body.gsub!(/(?=\b).+(?=\b)/) {|m| subs[m]}
```

Comment: +1 Using a hash is an excellent way to do a global search-and-replace.

Comment: It may work if `subs` default_proc just returns the missing key.

Comment: Thanks! But what does {|k| k} mean?

Comment: @user2592038: it's a block that returns its only argument, `k`.

Answer (score 5):

```
subs = {
  "you" => "he",
  "up" => "down",
  "in" => "out"}

# generate a regular expression; 300 keys is fine but much more is not.
re = Regexp.union(subs.keys)

p "you are in!".gsub(re, subs)
# => "he are out!"

body.gsub(re, subs)
```

Comment: Thanks!But in this answer, How to communicate with the body input?

Comment: You brought up a good point - the keys in the hash have to be equal to the substring matched in the regexp. So if you just want to match all the keys in the string, you have to make a regexp with union of all the keys.